# LoRa: application layer receiving fragmented packets for each received transmission?

Tags: iot, lora, lorawan

I am using Ebyte ttl-1w-433 RF module attached with a raspberry pi. When I send a packet, the receiver receives it but in my program(application layer) it prints the data in two fragments. I am using pySerial for my program. Below is the scenario that I am facing problem with-

1. sender sending 2 packets of 58 bytes each.
2. receiver receives two transmissions, and two only (receiver LED light blinks only twice)
3. receiver pushes the data in the application layer as 48, 10, 48, 10 fashion, instead of 58, 58 bytes fashion.
   4.application layer(python script) prints four print statements (instead of two)

I am not loosing any data, I am just curious why data arriving app layer fragmented.  tried with different serial baud rate and air data rate combination, but I always see the same pattern.

Comment: what spreading factor do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `Ebyte ttl-1w-433` module but it uses the `Semtech SX1276` chip. The SX1276 has a register `RegPayloadLength` (see [SX1272 datasheet](https://www.semtech.com/uploads/documents/DS_SX1276-7-8-9_W_APP_V5.pdf), page 114) which defines the payload length. Maybe your Raspberry Pi library (or whatsoever) which controls the access to the module, defines a fixed length of max. 48 bytes on initialization. Since you did not provide any code this is just a wild guess.